# Overwriting My yaml Syntax

Tags: python, yaml

When I am loading my yaml file I am getting output in dictonary format but mykeys are getting overwritten. Any help please.

Find below my yaml file.

```
 import yaml

 my_name: value0
   my_flavors: ['large']
   my_ip: '10.222.25.200'
   my_user: ubuntu
   my_pass: ubuntu
   my_config: /home/ubuntu
   my_net_type: vlan
   my_switch_type: ovs
   my_knobs:
     dp: no
     dk : no
     sk: no
   my_monitor: yes
 my_name: value1
   my_flavors: ['large',small]
   my_ip: '10.222.35.200'
   my_user: ubuntu
   my_pass: ubuntu
   my_config: /home/ubuntu/
   my_net_type: vlan
   my_switch_type: ovs
   my_knobs:
     dp: no
     dk : no
     sr: no
   my_monitor: yes
```

I should not change my key but when I get o/p I am getting  only value 1 details not value 0. How do I get all details in dictionary format?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. This format translates to a dict, and a dict can only have one value for a key; you can't have multiple `my_name` keys.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve no deep knowledge about yaml files, but I think the problem is cause your "key" are equal.

Only the last value for each "key" will be displayed, so you should try something like:

```
my_name_0: value0
   my_flavors: ['large']
   my_ip: '10.222.25.200'
   my_user: ubuntu
   my_pass: ubuntu
   my_config: /home/ubuntu
   my_net_type: vlan
   my_switch_type: ovs
   my_knobs:
     dp: no
     dk : no
     sk: no
   my_monitor: yes
my_name_1: value1
   my_flavors: ['large',small]
   my_ip: '10.222.35.200'
   my_user: ubuntu
   my_pass: ubuntu
   my_config: /home/ubuntu/
   my_net_type: vlan
   my_switch_type: ovs
   my_knobs:
     dp: no
     dk : no
     sr: no
   my_monitor: yes
```

Important is the "my_name_x" to make the key unique.